# substr add � at the end of string in php

Tags: php

I have one string , string is like this.

```
$Result;
$name = 'á é í ó ú ¿ ¡ ü';

preg_match_all('#(?<=\s|\b)\p{L}#ui', $name, $Result);
print_r($Result);
```

$Result is `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => á [1] => é [2] => í [3] => ó [4] => ú [5] => ü ) )`

Now i am using a implode.

```
$ret = implode('', $Result[0]);
echo $ret; // it is print like this: áéíóúü
```

Now i want only first 3 character from this string. But it is return with the ?.

```
$ret = substr($ret, 0, 3);
echo $ret // it is print like this: á�
```

My expected result is : `áéí`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string has multibyte encoding (like **UTF-8**) does, you should use [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) to avoid problems like this:

```
$ret = mb_substr($ret, 0, 3);
echo $ret;
```

The [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) just counts bytes while [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) counts characters.

Comment: thank you so much , i will accept your answer once SO allow to me accept

Answer (score 1):

Use the [mb_substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) function instead which handles multibyte characters.